# Why is my custom useFetch hook causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

This is the react custom hook that I use to fetch data throughout my App. I did not encounter problems when I used this hook to fetch data based on user's input query.

useFetch.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import apiKey from "../apiKey";

function useFetch() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function fetchData(
    url,
    options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": apiKey,
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "unogsng.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    }
  ) {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setData(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return [data, error, loading, fetchData];
}

export default useFetch;
```

This is the homepage of my App. I want the homepage to display the newest shows that are released today. I encountered an infinite loop when I tried to use useEffect to fetch the API.

Home.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

const Home = () => {
  const [newShows, setNewShows] = useState([]);
  const [data, error, loading, fetchData] = useFetch();
  const today = new Date();
  const date = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  const url = `https://unogsng.p.rapidapi.com/search?newdate=${date}&limit=10`;
  console.log(date);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(url);
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return <h1>Home</h1>;
};

export default Home;
```

I tried using url as dependency but it did not fetch the API on mount.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(url);
    console.log(data);
  }, [url]);
```

It does't work with no dependency either.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(url);
    console.log(data);
  }, []);
```

Comment: `[data]`  because data is different every time,  data is not a depenancy here anyway, you really want `[url]`..

Comment: Off Topic: you don't properly manage your state. You could have a state where you're `loading`, have `data` and an `error` from different requests all at the same time. These 3 things are not independent of each other, they should be a single state: `const [{ data, error, loading=false}, setState] = useState({});` and set the state accordingly. loading: `setState({ loading: true })` success: `setState({ data: jsonData })` error: `setState({ error: err })`

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data only when the component mounts; so use an empty dependency array for `useEffect`. (You might want to put `url` in the dependency array if it may change.)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(url);
}, []);
```

Then, display the data conditionally in the JSX:

```
return <>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  {data ? <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre> : <p>Loading</p>}
</>;
```